# Google Maps API: How to get Zip Code from lat/lng coordinates?

Tags: javascript, html, google-geocoder

How can I use Google Maps API to obtain the zipcode from lat/lng coordinates?

**Here's what I have tried so far**

I have the code below which I am using to get Zipcode of the person on the webpage. It loads the latitude and longitude but its failing creating geocode object, the alert for GeoCoderStatus is not firing. Not sure where I am doing wrong any pointers, please:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=true"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">       
            function geoloc() {
                if (navigator.geolocation) {                
                    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
                        function (pos) {                       
                            alert(pos.coords.longitude);
                            GeoToZip(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude);
                        }, function (err) {
                            alert(err.message);
                        }
                    );
                } else {
                    alert('Geolocation unsupported!');
                }
            }
            function GeoToZip(lat, lng) {            
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);          
                var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();             

                try {
                    geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': latlng }, function (res, status) {

         **alert(google.maps.GeocoderStatus);**
                        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK && typeof res[0] !== 'undefined') {
                            var zip = res[0].formatted_address.match(/,\s\w{2}\s(\d{5})/);

                            if (zip) {
                                alert(zip[1]);
                            } else fail('Failed to parse');
                        } else {
                            fail('Failed to reverse');
                        }
                    });
                }
                catch (err) {
                    alert(err);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Geocoder request doesn't have property `latLng`, the correct name is `location`: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?#GeocoderRequest

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Latitude and longitude can find zip code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6764917/latitude-and-longitude-can-find-zip-code)