# Google is not defined in the function: geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder()

Tags: javascript, geolocation, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I tried to replicate the function that takes Lat and Long and return ZIP Code using Javascript and Snowflake. The code is from the SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6764917/latitude-and-longitude-can-find-zip-code). (Code Credits to @HBlackorby )

Below is the function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION STAGING.SDS.GET_ZIP_CODE(latitude FLOAT, longitude FLOAT)
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
AS
$$
function getzip(lat, lng) {
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            if (results[0]) {
                for (j = 0; j < results[0].address_components.length; j++) {
                    if (results[0].address_components[j].types[0] == 'postal_code')
                        alert("Zip Code: " + results[0].address_components[j].short_name);
                }
            }
        } else {
            alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
        }
    });
}
$$
```

Output:

```
SELECT STAGING.SDS.GET_ZIP_CODE('39.041519165', '-77.111801147');

JavaScript execution error: Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined in GET_ZIP_CODE at 'var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);' position 13 stackstrace: getzip line: 3 GET_ZIP_CODE line: 18
```

Expected Output:

```
20852
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only use objects from the [JavaScript standard library](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects) and the [Stored Procedure API](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/stored-procedures-api.html).
  You can't import any external libraries like those from google (as of Oct, 2019).