# How to obtain the zip code from Google Maps Geocoder API

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps

I need to obtain the zip code from a given address using the Google Maps Geocoder API. I have been able to get other data, such as longitude and latitude, but obtaining the zip code is just a little bit different. The Json I am trying to parse the zip code from is:

```
    {
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "1600",
               "short_name" : "1600",
               "types" : [ "street_number" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Amphitheatre Parkway",
               "short_name" : "Amphitheatre Pkwy",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Mountain View",
               "short_name" : "Mountain View",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Santa Clara County",
               "short_name" : "Santa Clara County",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "California",
               "short_name" : "CA",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "United States",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "94043",
               "short_name" : "94043",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy, Mountain View, CA 94043, USA",
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 37.4267861,
               "lng" : -122.0806032
            },
```

The javascript function I have written is:

```
        async function getZipCode() {
        const searchedAddress = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(ViewData["searchString"]));
        const response = await axios.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json', {
            params: {
                address: searchedAddress,
                key: [key],
                sensor: 'true_or_false'
            }
        })
            let addressComponents = response.data.results[0].address_components;
            for (var i = 0; i < addressComponents.count; i++) {
                if (addressComponents[i].types == 'postal_code') {
                    let zip = response.data.results[0].address_components[i].short_name;
                    return zip;
                    console.log(zip);
                }
            }

         }
```

I know, for the data provided in this json example, I can obtain the postal_code with

```
response.data.results[0].address_components[6].short_name;
```

but this is not always the case. Sometimes the postal code is contained in a different iteration of address_components, so I need to come up with a way to check for the type and then get the short_name.

The function I have is not returning anything to the console. I realize that the console.log statement is within the "if" statement, but am drawing a blank on how to actually get this data.

Comment: Duplicate of [Latitude and longitude can find zip code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6764917/latitude-and-longitude-can-find-zip-code)

Answer (score 1):

You're pretty close in your attempt. Where it seems you've gone awry is here:

```
if (addressComponents[i].types == 'postal_code') { // ...
```

What you're asking the interpreter to figure out is if `addressComponents[i].types` is equal to *the string* `postal_code`, when we know that `types` seems to always be an Array. In most all setups, Arrays can't be coerced directly to strings.

What you're *actually* trying to figure out is if the string `postal_code` exists *within* the Array. As such, you can use [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```
if (addressComponents[i].types.includes('postal_code')) { // process the postal code data
```

---

Aside: anything after a `return` won't get executed, so you wouldn't see the output from `console.log(zip)` using your code in any event, success or not. Using an IDE with solid syntax highlighting may have alerted you to this by showing the code that wouldn't get executed in a lighter opacity - I would recommend beginning to use one straight away if you aren't already.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This, along with changing addressComponents.count to addressComponents.length did the trick.